# Wimpod respawn rate?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

On Route 8, a Wimpod was there on regular playthrough. I encountered it, lowered it below 50% HP (trying to catch it) and he ran away.

I wasn't able to re-spawn straight after, so I just kept going on my journey.

Now that I'm done with the main story line (a week or so later), I came back there, expecting to see another Wimpod. To my great disappointment, nothing was there to be seen.

My question is: Does it re-spawn at any point or day? Or will I have to trade to get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wimpod respawns at a rate of every 24 hours. It's important to note that changing your clock will reset the respawn timer, so *don't do that*!

From [here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/187276-pokemon-sun/74638654):

> It respawns after 24 hours in all three spots. I messed up my route 8 spawn because my 3DS date was 2017 instead of 2016. Changing the clock resets the timer for another 24 hours.

[This article](https://www.google.com/amp/www.itechpost.com/amp/articles/56418/20161121/pok%C3%A9mon-sun-moon-tips-tricks-easily-catch-wimpod.htm?client=safari) also supports the 24 respawn timer:

> once you fail on your first try you'll have to wait for its next spawn on the following day

If it's still not showing up, I'd recommend looking in the other two locations that Wimpod spawns. From [this Serebii page](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-sm/location/767.shtml#sun), it appears that you can also find Wimpod in Poni Breaker Coast and Poni Wilds.

Comment: But it wasn't there for me a week later (and no I didn't play with the clock). Does it spawn only at a certain time of the day ?

Comment: @Karlyr yeah, that's odd. Have you tried the other two locations? The way some of the things I'm reading are worded could be interpreted as it only respawns if you miss it in all three locations.

Comment: Found it in poni wilds on the beach side (even though it wasn't there the first and second time I was looking for him)

Comment: Note that it was the only one I saw in those three spots. Might be because only one of the three spots have it or something along those lines...

Comment: I definitely watched a video where someone was able to get it to spawn by simply entering and leaving the area immediately after catching it, without waiting 24 hours. When I find the video I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: I think there's only one at a time. If it doesn't spawn on Route 8, it should be in one of the other locations. It should always be in one of them, but which one it is in at any specific time appears to be random.

Comment: @scenia that makes sense and would explain what happened with Karlyr

Comment: I can confirm that resetting the DS time didn't seem to cause a problem with spawning when I caught Wimpod

Answer (score 0):

I was able to catch Wimpods by just repeatedly entering Route 8 and seeing if one was standing there. I caught two back to back that way.

I also reset my DS time to earlier in the day to test if that caused them not to spawn and it didn't seem to have any effect.

I think for future Wimpods hunters the best bet is to just repeatedly enter one of the areas (Route 8 has a zone exit nearby so that one is easy) until you see one waiting.

As far as catching the little cowards, [these](https://redd.it/5er3zn) steps helped me. I was able to use Sharpedo to break the rocks in the water to the south of Route 8, and then wait in front of the hole until the Wimpod ran into me triggering the fight. After that it was relatively simple to just sleep the Pokemon and fling ultra balls at it.